# Laravel Eloquent query/subquery with no values throws error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

All of my departments need to submit various reports each quarter: budget, HR, etc. I want to show a table that shows all of the required reports for the logged-in user's department (all departments must submit the same reports), a boolean if they have submitted it, and a boolean if that file is considered valid. I'm having problems mostly with the boolean values.

I have three tables: `reports` stores the `id`, `name`, and `due_date`; `file_uploads` stores the `id`, `report_id`, `filename`, and `department_id`; `file_upload_errors` stores `id`, `file_upload_id`, and `error`.

In order to build the table to display to the user, I've queried the Reports table:

```
$data = Reports::with([
    'file_uploads' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('department_id', '=', user()->department_id);
    },
    'file_uploads.file_upload_errors'
])->get();
```

Next, I need to map the data to my view model:

```
$vm = array();
//map the data to the view model
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $mapping = new DataRequestsViewModel();
    $mapping->ReportName = $value->name;
    $mapping->DueDate = $value->due_date;
    $mapping->IsUploaded = ($value->file_uploads->count() > 0) ? true : false;
    $mapping->IsValid = ($value->file_uploads->file_upload_errors->count() < 1) ? true : false;
    $vm[] = $mapping;
}
```

However, I'm getting an exception: `Property [file_upload_errors] does not exist on this collection instance.`

I understand this is because if the user has not yet uploaded the file, then it can't query the relationship of `null` to see if there are any `file_upload_errors` but I don't know how to handle it... Can someone show me a good approach?

---

I didn't actually end up using `empty()` when all is said and done, but it did lead me down the right path... here's what I ended up with:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
            $mapping = new DataRequestsViewModel();
            $mapping->TemplateId = $value->id;
            $mapping->TemplateName = $value->name;
            $mapping->DueDate = $value->due_date;
            $mapping->IsUploaded = ($value->file_uploads->count() > 0) ? true : false;
            if ($mapping->IsUploaded == false) {
                $mapping->IsValid = false;
            } else {
                $mapping->IsValid = $value->file_uploads->first()->file_upload_errors->count() < 1 ? true : false;
            }
            $vm[] = $mapping;
        }
```

Comment: Is the error thrown when you fetch the data or when you try to map it?

Comment: When I try to map it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't handle it :)
If there is no error then there is no need to count them. I'd use this instead:

```
$mapping->IsValid = empty($value->file_uploads->file_upload_errors) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Though I sense logic errors here.. What type of relationship is between `Reports` and `file_uploads` ?

Comment: it is a one to many - a report has many uploads (one per `department_id`).

Comment: this makes it so there is no exception thrown, but I don't seem to be getting the correct results. `IsValid` is always true, even if there are upload errors. I dumped `$data` and confirmed there is an entry for `file_upload_errors` (if there is an error, it should be false)

Comment: figured it out.. i needed to get the first result object so it looks like `empty($value->file_uploads->first()->file_upload_errors)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally guessing here, but I think it's because you're doing a custom query on your `file_uploads`, that you actually lose the built-in `file_uploads.file_upload_errors` mapping.

Moving the `with` inside the `file_uploads` query, it will append it to that collection properly.

Perhaps this will work:

```
$data = Reports::with([
    'file_uploads' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('department_id', '=', user()->department_id)
        ->with('file_upload_errors');
    },
])->get();
```